# Calculate and order the number of referrals for each referrer

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'll preface this by saying I'm new to rails and development.

**Overview**

I have a simple referral system, and I want to calculate the number of times each subscriber has referred someone else, then put all subscribers in descending order based on the number of referrals.

**Details**

Here's my `Subscribers` table:

```
| id | email | referred_by |
```

`referred_by` contains the `subscriber_id` of the referring subscriber.

What I want is a method / query that loops through every subscriber in the table and:

1. Counts the number of times their id appears in the `referred_by` columns.
2. Orders subscribers by the total number of referrals they have.

I was thinking along the lines of the below, but part of my problem is that I don't know where and how I can test methods and queries outside of the codebase, so I don't how to test this. I assume in the console, but I don't understand how to do multi-part methods or queries there.

```
Subscriber.all.each do |referrer|
  Subscriber.all.each do |subscriber|
    if referrer.id == subscriber.referred_by
      referrals += 1
    else
      next
    end
  end
end
# Then order descending
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select A.id
      ,A.email
      ,case when B.referrals is null then 0 else  B.referrals end as referrals
 From YourTable A
 Left Join ( 
        Select referred_by,count(*) as referrals
         From  YourTable 
         Where referred_by is not null
         Group By referred_by
      ) B 
    On A.id = B.referred_by
 Order By B.referrals Desc,A.email
```

Would return something like this

```
id  email               referrals 
4   email_4@mail.com    3
1   email_1@mail.com    2
2   email_2@mail.com    0
3   email_3@mail.com    0
```

> **EDIT**

If you want to exclude non-referrals (zero counts) change Left Join to Inner Join

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is to use the rails :counter_cache option for the belongs_to association.  Add a column in your table called "referrals_count" (or something you like better) which will keep a count of all the subscribers referred by them.  I think you also need to change your "referred_by" column to "referred_by_id" so you can set the association up correctly. Your Subscriber model would look like:

```
class Subscriber < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :referred_by, class_name: "Subscriber", counter_cache: :referrals_count
end
```

Then your query would be:

```
@subscribers = Subscriber.order(referrals_count: :desc)
```

You can get more information on Rails counter_cache here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

I prefer doing it this way so I don't have to write long and complicated sql queries.

Comment: Thanks. I read through the documentation, but I'm not entirely sure I understand how this works.  Couple questions: 1) Is there something additional I need to do in my subscribers controller to account for or save `referrals_count`? The post isn't processing as is. 2) Why would "referred_by" need to be "referred_by_id"?

Comment: 1) The `referrals_count` is automatically updated by adding that `counter_cache: :referrals_count` to the belongs to association for `referred_by_id`. So in your migration for adding`referrals_count` to Subscribers make sure you give it a type of integer and a default of 0: `add_column :subscribers, :referrals_count, :integer, default: 0`.

Comment: 2) You need to change `referred_by` to `referred_by_id` so you can properly set up the belongs_to association.  Rails expects any association columns to have "_id" at the end since it expects the data in the column to be the id of that object.  In this case its the subscriber's id that referred them.  Check out the belongs_to section of that link I sent too, it goes over this part too.  ActiveRecord Associations is one of the key fundamentals of Ruby on Rails so I definitely recommend reading through the link I included because its going to save you LOTS of time in your code writing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a task best left to your database, which has all sorts of optimizations for exactly these tasks.

```
# Fetch subs who have referred others, ordered by number of referrals
referrers = Subscriber.group('referrer_id').order('count(referrer_id) desc')

# Select number of referrals alongside referrer data
referrers = referrers.select('count(referrer_id) as referral_count').select('*')

# Example of using the data:
referrers.each do |referrer|
  puts "#{referrer.name} referred #{referrer.referral_count} others"
end
```

With a small data set, this will suffice, but you will probably want to chain on a `limit`, or even set a floor on the number of referrals (i.e., only show users with at least 1 referral) with `having`.

Normally I'd also convert the strings in here to make better use of Arel, but it complicates the solution making it harder to grok, so I've not done so. Homework for another time!

Note: I've used slightly different terms/columns here to make this example easier to understand and follow. Make sure you don't blindly copy-paste. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing this as an sqlstatement letting the database do the work for you rather than looping.  SQLServers are far more adept at this sort of thing

```
select referred_by, 
   (select email 
      from subscribers sub 
      where id = subscribers.referred_by) as email,
   count(referred_by) as referred
from subscribers 
group by referred_by
order by count(referred_by) desc
```

this would be in the database itself as a stored procedure then I'd call that from the application. it's not rubyesq but it puts the work where it belongs.